# Where get_active_posted_job_by_id function in ci

Tags: codeigniter

```
public function get_active_posted_job_by_id($id){ 

    $Q = $this->db->query("CALL get_active_posted_job_by_id($id)"); 
    if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){ 
      $return = $Q->row(); 
    } else { 
       $return = 0; 
    } 
    $Q->next_result();
    $Q->free_result(); 
    return $return; 
}
```

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: this is use for model in  mysql query,But code for only use to call function,But get_active_posted_job_by_id($id); function in none, function return  all record displayed

Comment: add proper code in your question. Now difficult to understand

Comment: public function get_active_posted_job_by_id($id) {
       $Q = $this->db->query("CALL get_active_posted_job_by_id($id)");
        if ($Q->num_rows() > 0) {
            $return = $Q->row();
        } else {
            $return = 0;
        }
  $Q->next_result();
        $Q->free_result();
        return $return;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
return $this->db->get_where('table_name', ['id' => $id])->row();
```

This will give only one record according to `$id`

Comment: public function count_searched_job_records($param,$param2) {
  $Q = $this->db->query('CALL count_ft_search_job("'.$param.'","'.$param2.'")'); 
   if ($Q->num_rows() > 0) {
            $return = $Q->row('total');
        } else {
            $return = 0;
        }
  $Q->next_result();
        $Q->free_result();
        return $return;
  
    }

Comment: where count_ft_search_job() function, this function not in controller and model